# Indentation and syntax in vim for non-standard elements

Tags: html, angularjs, vim, polymer

I'm writing a app in Polymer (and I have the same issue with custom angular directives).

For HTML elements like `div`, `span`, etc the indentation and highlighting works fine in Vim.

For custom directives/elements like `<paper-tabs>` it does not. Indentation leaves them all on the same line, and highlighting is broken:

[image: Example of broken indentation]

How can I make vim take all elements at the beginning of a `<elementname attribute="value">` and treat them like a normal HTML element - like `<div>` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use https://github.com/othree/html5.vim.git with Pathogen. Doesn't help too much with indentation, but highlighting works correctly.

Comment: This helps with indentation for AngularJS Material Design Directives/Elements. One may need to restart vim after installing it by using `vundle`.

Comment: I found this helped with indenting: https://github.com/mgiuffrida/vim2/blob/patch-1/runtime/indent/html.vim